# How to Move from one page to another in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to move from 1 page to another page and for that I have write below code in `home.page.html` file.

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <ion-button (click)="goToLoginPage()" size="large">Continue</ion-button>
</div>
```

Below is `home.page.ts` file code.

```js
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navController: NavController) {

  }

  goToLoginPage(){
    this.navController.navigateForward(LoginVCPage) // Getting error at this line.
  }
}
```

Below is error screenshot.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/ionic-4-routing-and-navigation-guide/ i hope this helps

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Thanks for the link

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Ionic 4 using `NavController` is deprecated. See this statement from the [Migration Guide](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/building/migration/#navigation):

> In V4, navigation received the most changes. Now, instead of using
> Ionic's own NavController, we integrate with the official Angular
> Router.

Angular manages it's routes in a separate file, in Ionic 4 this file is named `app-routing.module.ts`. Every time you create a new page using `ionic g page pagename` the CLI will automatically create a new entry in the `routes` array in `app-routing.module.ts`.

So assuming you have created a test page and now have following routes in `app-routing.module.ts`:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'test', loadChildren: './test/test.module#TestPageModule' },
];
```

You can move to another page by adding a href property to your button with the corresponding path (e.g. `'/test'`) to the page you want to move to:

```html
<ion-button href="/test">Move to test page</ion-button>
```

You could also use the `routerLink` directive as pointed out [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation#navigating-to-different-routes):

```html
<ion-button [routerLink]="['/test']">Move to test page</ion-button>
```

---

If you want/need to navigate programmatically you'll have to inject the router service into your page/component and call [`navigateByUrl`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigatebyurl) like so:

```js
constructor(private router: Router) { }

goToTestPage() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/test');
}
```

Also see the [Angular docs on routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) and the [Ionic v4 docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/navigation) on this topic.

Comment: How to go from test to home? I have login page & dashboard. When i go from dashboard to login . I m using "this.router.navigate(['/login']);". It goes in loop

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Phonolog 's answer you should also use `routerDirection="forward"` or whatever direction it may be.